# re map fftw_complex to Matrixcd in Eigen lib

Tags: c++, dictionary, eigen

I would like to map fftw_complex array to Eigen MatrixXcd and back: I found this:

```
MatrixXcd m1 = MatrixXcd::Map(reinterpret_cast<complex<double>*>(m1f), n1, n2);
```

but seems to be slow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should fix the performance problem:

```
MatrixXcd::Map<MatrixXcd> m1(reinterpret_cast<complex<double>*>(m1f), n1, n2);
```

The problem is that you assign the Map object to a Matrix object. This forces Eigen to *copy* the mapped matrix into the memory allocated by the Matrix object.

Additionally, you might want to consider using `MatrixXcd::Map<MatrixXcd, Aligned>`. This tells Eigen that the memory pointed to by `m1f` is properly aligned for vectorization. But of course you have to make sure that your memory is indeed properly aligned as required by Eigen.

Comment: Multiple markers at this line
 - expected ';' before 'Load_mat'
 - statement cannot resolve address of overloaded 
  function

Comment: MatrixXcd::Map<MatrixXcd> Load_mat(reinterpret_cast<complex<double>*>(input3), w, h);

Comment: delte MatrixXcd::Map error disappear; but it seems like data no map...outputs are zeros..